# Oil spray on windshield, running rough, and smoking

Tags: engine, ford

I have a 1992 Ford F150. It has been leaking oil. There is water in the oil. Yesterday, it spewed oil onto my windshield and began running very raggedly with smoke pouring out of the tailpipes. Is it likely that I just blew a gasket, threw a rod, blew a head or blew the motor?

Comment: Onto your windshield?! Can you tell where it came from, or how it got there?

Comment: Can you say buy a newer truck............

Comment: @Moab '92 F150? That thing should run for another 20 years with proper maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes, in order of severity and cost:

- Gasket below the cylinder head is broken
- Gasket below the cylinder assembly is broken
- Cylinder head itself has fissures between water and oil channels.
- Cylinder assembly has fissures between water and oil channels.

I bet it's the gasket below the cylinder head only. Don't move the car any more as the oil/water mixture also leaks into the exhaust and will eventually damage the oxygen sensor and the catalytic converter.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "gasket below the cylinder assembly?" Do you mean the oil pan gasket? They're cheap and fairly easy on that truck. And the big issue with driving with a blown *head gasket* is that the coolant doesn't lubricate, and can seize the engine, not so much that it'll damage the cat. (It CAN damage the cat, but that's way cheaper than a new engine.)

Comment: Not specific for that model but there can also be a gasket below the cylinder block/cylinder assembly towards the crankcase.